# Get Specific XML Data In C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have below xml(in 1 file)

```
<ROW QUALIFYPREFIX="PayerAddressChildItem_R1_" PKEY="2128465">
<COL NAME="IsDefault" TYPE="FieldTypeBoolean" HIDDEN="1" OVALUE="0" VALUE="0" DVALUE="No" />
<COL NAME="AddressType" TYPE="FieldTypeValidValues" OVALUE="Billing" VALUE="Billing" DVALUE="Billing" />
<COL NAME="AddressLine1" TYPE="FieldTypeVarchar" OVALUE="111 sts" VALUE="111 sts" DVALUE="111 sts" />
<COL NAME="AddressLine2" TYPE="FieldTypeVarchar" OVALUE="" VALUE="" DVALUE="" />
<COL NAME="City" TYPE="FieldTypeVarchar" OVALUE="new york" VALUE="new york" DVALUE="new york" />
<COL NAME="State" TYPE="FieldTypeState" OVALUE="NC" VALUE="NC" DVALUE="NC" />
<COL NAME="Zip" TYPE="FieldTypeZipCode" OVALUE="10010" VALUE="10010" DVALUE="10010" />
<COL NAME="BasedOn" TYPE="FieldTypeValidValues" OVALUE="Billed Date" VALUE="Billed Date" DVALUE="Billed Date" />
<COL NAME="EffectiveDate" TYPE="FieldTypeDate" OVALUE="4/22/2016 12:00:00 AM" VALUE="4/22/2016" DVALUE="4/22/2016" />
<COL NAME="ExpirationDate" TYPE="FieldTypeDate" OVALUE="" VALUE="" DVALUE="" />
</ROW>

<ROW QUALIFYPREFIX="PayerAddressChildItem_R2_" REQUEST="WRITE">
<COL NAME="IsDefault" TYPE="FieldTypeBoolean" HIDDEN="1" OVALUE="" VALUE="" DVALUE="Unknown" />
<COL NAME="AddressType" TYPE="FieldTypeValidValues" OVALUE="" VALUE="Billing" DVALUE="Billing" />
<COL NAME="AddressLine1" TYPE="FieldTypeVarchar" OVALUE="" VALUE="111 sts" DVALUE="111 sts" />
<COL NAME="AddressLine2" TYPE="FieldTypeVarchar" OVALUE="" VALUE="" DVALUE="" />
<COL NAME="City" TYPE="FieldTypeVarchar" OVALUE="" VALUE="new york" DVALUE="new york" />
<COL NAME="State" TYPE="FieldTypeState" OVALUE="" VALUE="AE" DVALUE="AE" />
<COL NAME="Zip" TYPE="FieldTypeZipCode" OVALUE="" VALUE="10010" DVALUE="10010" />
<COL NAME="BasedOn" TYPE="FieldTypeValidValues" OVALUE="" VALUE="Billed Date" DVALUE="Billed Date" />
<COL NAME="EffectiveDate" TYPE="FieldTypeDate" OVALUE="" VALUE="4/23/2016" DVALUE="4/23/2016" />
<COL NAME="ExpirationDate" TYPE="FieldTypeDate" OVALUE="" VALUE="" DVALUE="" />
</ROW>
```

I want store only the VALUE of *COL NAME="EffectiveDate"* in a list. In this case there are 2. Value of the first EffectiveDate = 4/22/2016 and for the second EffectiveDate = 4/23/2016.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your data *isn't* a valid XML document. You could make it a valid document by adding a dummy root element.

Once you've valid `Xml` you could simply do `Linq` to `Xml`.

```
XDocument root = XDocument.Load(filepath);

var results = root
    .Descendants("COL")
    .Where(x=>x.Attribute("NAME").Value == "EffectiveDate")
    .Select(x=>x.Attribute("VALUE").Value);
```

**Output**

```
4/22/2016
4/23/2016
```

Have a look this [`demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FUcReP)